# Should we convert false Purim Torah questions to regular questions?

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy, vote-to-close

The Purim Torah season has been open for barely a day, and there are already five questions closed as not real Purim Torah.

Should we consider the possibility that some of these questions were actually intended as serious questions (and were just mistagged), and therefore instead of closing them we should simply remove the Purim Torah tag and disclaimer and let them exist as regular questions?

Or do we say that it is up to the asker to correctly post his/her question, and if he/she tags a question as Purim Torah it's not our job to convert it to a regular question?

If we go with the first option, would it only be where there is strong reason to believe that the questioner intended it to be a serious question, or should we simply convert any question that is technically a serious question?

This may warrant a separate post, but if we are seeing many examples of such questions does that indicate that the Purim Torah policy is not properly explained/understood? What can we do to help people understand what types of questions are Purim Torah and what types are serious questions?

Comment: While five were closed, your suggestion of reopening as serious wouldn’t help for [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100411/).

Comment: If it helps, the other four are https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100395/, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100393/, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100289/, and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100401/. It should be noted that three of them were posted by the same person, so I don’t think that this is indicative of a systemic issue of not understanding the policy.

Comment: @DonielF True (unless there’s a hidden question there).

Comment: The tone of the post clearly indicates that it’s meant as Purim shtick; the problem with that one is that it’s not a good fit for a Q&A (though it might fit for the Jokeathon). The other four are all Q&A, but failing on the Purim Torah front.

Answer (score 5):

I am on Meta now! You are talking about my question. It is a question. I want to know what you want from me. It is Judaism. It is about a Judaism thing where you people call my name again and again. It is for Purim. It is really about a song not about people calling my name. I am not stupid. I know this is From When and not really my name. I am pretending to make it funny for Purim. It would not be funny to ask why you call FromWhenFromWhenFromWhenFromWhen. No one is named From When but I am named Misha. It is all of the things. Will you open it?

Comment: Welcome to meta (and to Mi Yodeya)!  Your question is open now.

Answer (score 4):

First, I’d like to distinguish between the five questions.

[PTIJ: What do you people want?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100411) was asked in a very Purimdik tone; the problem here is on the Q&A side, not the Purim side. I don’t see an easy way to preserve both.

Then there’s the other four:

- [PTIJ: I am very humble and I want you to know it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100395/)
- [PTIJ: What is the proper attire for women in Scotland?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100393/)
- [PTIJ: Siyum during the nine days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100289/)
- [PTIJ: What are their names?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100401/)

These are all Q&A but fail on the Purim front. (Incidentally, three of them were asked by the same person, so I don’t think it’s indicative of a systemic misunderstanding of the PTIJ policy.) We *could* conceivably scrap the PTIJ labels off of them and call it a day, but that seems like an edit which “clearly conflicts with the author’s intent.”

To me, the better approach is just the opposite: try to fix the posts to *retain* their PTIJ-ness. That way, the author’s intent is preserved, while the question can be reopened.

Comment: Regarding the first one, I hadn’t seen the revision when I posted this question.

Comment: I think the edits make the first one clearly both Purim and a question.  I'm reopening it.  (Edit: oh, I see it already had four reopen votes, even.)